# How determine machine type (i486,i586 or i586) or Processor Classification

Tags: linux, windows, architecture, processor

I want to deermine if a processor is i386, i486, i586 or i686, etc... but without using php (maybe is not installed ever)

Reviewing in Windows we have something like:

```
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE  x86
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER    x86 Family 6 Model 28 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL         6
PROCESSOR_REVISION      1c02
```

But running:

```
php_uname ('m');
```

I have this:

```
i586
```

Is it posible to determine it with Family or Level How?

Comment: That classification scheme is impossibly crude for today's world. The information returned by Windows is much more detailed but I wonder if it's actionable. What do you intend to do with the information?

Comment: I want to know how php determine php_uname('m'); to be replicate using other language...

Comment: @chepelucho, luckily PHP is open source! [`php_uname` is implemented in C](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/b209c273027c9697f2a7628ecd950780c089d614/ext/standard/info.c#L1215), and most of the interesting work is done in [`php_get_uname`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/b209c273027c9697f2a7628ecd950780c089d614/ext/standard/info.c#L527).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

This will display a lot of information about Your CPU